# Time string to date object conversion js angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am getting following string from REST api,
20160220
I want to make it 20/02/2016

I am using angularJS. So I will require a filter.
I have tried following

```
app.filter('myDateFilter', function() {

  return function(input) {

  var st = input;  
  var pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
  var date = new Date(st.replace(pattern, '$1-$2-$3'));

  return date;

  }

});
```

And in html I have used

```
                <td>
                    {{t["due-date"] | myDateFilter}}
                </td>
```

This returns 2016-02-20T00:00:00.000Z

Regular expression issue? Can you kindly give me proper code which should have been used instead to generate 20/02/2016.

Comment: _Regular expression issue_ Nah. It's because, you're passing the string to  `Date()`, time is automatically added.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the issue: the date you are getting is correct.

Comment: @pietro909 just edited to add what exactly i am trying to do.

Comment: @Tushar anyway to remove the time and get something like 20/02/2016 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively converting a `Date` into a string results in the output you are seeing:

```js
console.log(new Date()) // "2016-09-02T15:19:07.921Z"
```

Instead, make sure you format the date into a string manually before returning it. E.g. `toLocaleDateString()` converts the `Date` into a string, taking into account the browser's locale:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString()) // "09/02/2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is converting a `String` to a `Date()` object, which seems right to me. If you try to show your `Date()` object in your view, what you get is the default date format.

In order to customize the format in which your `Date()` object is showing, you need to chain another filter to your custom filter. In this case you need to use `date` filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

You would only need to add it to your template, like this:

```
<td>
    {{t["due-date"] | myDateFilter | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
</td>
```

This way `date` filter will take as input the `Date()` object returned by your custom `myDateFilter` filter and produce a `String` representing that object as output.

This is a nice example of how angular filters and filter chaining are supposed to be used.